# Error in class connection object store to localstorage Angular5

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular5

I am trying to store class connection object localstorage and get on next page in Angular5, but not receiving correct data object.

here is my code:
**In component file**

```
this.storage.setVariableToStorage('client', CircularJSON.stringify(client));
```

**In service file**

```
setVariableToStorage(key: string, value: string): void {
    (key == 'client' || key == 'user') ? this[key] = JSON.parse(value) : this[key] = value;
    this.storage.set(key, value);
}
```

and getting this storage on another component `console.log(this.storage.client)`

Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `this.storage.get('client')`

Comment: show me where is `console.log(this.storage.client)` located

Comment: @SujataChanda after using this, getting error  ERROR TypeError: "this.storage.get is not a function"

Comment: @Astacius this is my code
 getObjectData(): void{
    console.log(this.storage.client)
  }

on contact component file  and anything else you want ?

Comment: @RiteshDoomra and when do you call this function  `getObjectData()`

Comment: @Astacius on ngOnInit()

Comment: @RiteshDoomra so you want to show this value before it was stored?

Comment: on login component here is the response
https://ibb.co/nORCCp
on contact component here is the response
https://ibb.co/cAEXCp

Comment: @Astacius can I have you skype id, its urgent show I can show you my screen

Comment: @Astacius it was stored on login component and getting this on contact component

Comment: @RiteshDoomra do `console.log` in your `setVariableToStorage` after storing

Comment: @Astacius, its already stored first on a login component while login and then getting this on contact component

Comment: @Astacius only some of the properties are accessing in next component i.e. contacts which means values are passing but not the complete.

Comment: @RiteshDoomra Check your json object size limit if object exceed size limit then it will not show full data [Url](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2989317/9775003)